# Weak convergence and strong convergence in $L^1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a Lebesgue measurable set，$f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L
^1(\Omega)$ and $\|f_n\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\rightharpoonup\|f\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$, then can I say that $f_n → f$ strongly in $L^1(\Omega)$? And how to prove it if it is true?

Comment: Take $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $f_n=1+r_n$, where $r_n$ is the $n$'th Rademacher function. I think this furnishes a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that this statement is true in Hilbert Spaces and for $1<p<\infty$, I think for the case $p=1$ it does not hold as $L^1$ is not reflexive. You should be able to construct a counterexample using a Dirac-Sequence.